# How to refresh First window on Second independent Window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing one problem. There is one tab in which application opened.
In this tab there is one button which open the second Window having the different
funcationality. 
Now my problem is on second window click I want to refresh one table. 
Is there any way to get notification on second window close.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to go about this:

In the parent, assign opened window and set an interval to check for the status of that window.

```
var child = window.open('http://google.com');
var timer = setInterval(function()
{
    if (child.closed) {
        console.log("Child window closed, let's do something about that");   
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
}, 1000);
```

Another way to go is to listen for onbeforeunload event in child window and then do something to opener:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  window.opener.alert('closed now');
};
```

First method should be used when you have no direct control over opened window, but the second method is better because it doesn't require intervals and there's no lag.